# how to give space between card layout in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have card layout in ng-repeat. Here i have displayed 4 card in a row for laptop and 2 card for tab and 1 card for mobile. Also i have attached image for reference[image]

I want to show advertisement image after first row in every pagination of the ng-repeat like that shown in this image.

Comment: you can use $index in your ng-repeat to determine when the add should be shown something like this: ng-if="$index%2 === 0"

Comment: i tired this way but ad shown after every row in ng-repeat.i want to show ad only after the first row in each pagination(dont show after 2 row and 3 row etc)

Comment: pls provide some code...